# How to avoid this case of evil eval?

Tags: javascript, eval, jslint, jshint

I inherited a javascript code base and I am new to javascript. So i am using JSHint to avoid common mistakes, misuses.

JSHint has found this piece of code but i do not know how to avoid the evil eval:

```
function GetProperties(object) {
    var result, property, t;
    result = '';
    for (property in object) {
        if (property.indexOf('Get', 0) === 0) {
            t = object[property] + "...";
            eval("if (GetNumOfParameter(t) == 0) var m = object." + property + "(); else var m = -100;");

            if (window.m != -100) {
                result += property + ': ' + window.m + '\r\n';
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: `var m = object[property]()` perhaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following, it's far better, you don't need to use `m` if you don't use it anywhere else.

```
function GetProperties(object) {
    var result, property, t;
    result = '';
    for (property in object) {
        if (property.indexOf('Get', 0) === 0) {
            t = object[property] + "...";

            if (GetNumOfParameter(t) == 0) 
                result += property + ': ' + object[property]() + '\r\n';
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Instead of (for instance) `GetNumOfParameter(t) == 0`, you can simply `!GetNumOfParameter(t)`